# iOS: Enable Navigation during loading overlay

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, frame, cgrect

In my xamarin iOS app I have a list view, I want to show the loading icon when it is being loading. But, I do not want to disable the whole page. I want the user to still go back if they wish to, using back navigation.

I used [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) as a reference.

So, I'm trying to set the CGRect Frame, to leave the navigation on the top active and disable the rest of the page during loading status.

I am using something like this: `new CGRect(30, 0,0, 0)` to leave 30 units from the top but it doesnt work. Can anyone help me out to have a frame to leave just navigation bar and cover rest of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoLayout is a much better way to accomplish this task than using frames. Unless you need to target REALLY, REALLY old versions of iOS, AutoLayout is generally the way to go.

I'm assuming you are using a `UIViewController` and not a `UITableViewController`. This is an important distinction, because the `UITableViewController` only allows you to add to the `UITableView` which makes this task much more challenging.

Add this `AddAnOverlay` method to your `UIViewController` class, then call it whenever you want to display an overlay. You will probably need to put `overlay` in an instance variable so that you can remove it later. Remove it by calling `overlay.RemoveFromSuperview()` and you're done.

```
    void AddAnOverlay()
    {
        var overlay = new UIView();
        overlay.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.ColorWithAlpha(0.45f); // or whatever colo
        overlay.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        var label = new UILabel();
        label.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        label.Text = "Loading Fantastic Things!";

        var spinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView();
        spinner.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        spinner.StartAnimating();

        overlay.AddSubview(spinner);
        overlay.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, spinner, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
        overlay.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, spinner, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));

        overlay.AddSubview(label);
        // can adjust space between by changing -30 to whatever
        overlay.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(spinner, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, label, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, -30));
        overlay.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, label, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));

        View.AddSubview(overlay);
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(BottomLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, overlay, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
    }
```

Notice the `TopLayoutGuide` and `BottomLayoutGuide` in the `NSLayoutConstraint`. These represent the top and bottom of your current view controller, so they can be used to size things so they don't hide navigation bars, tab bars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the overlay to the table view, which leads you to a centering problem. For this there are some options: recalculate the position of the overlay when scrolling, add an additional layer behind the table view which you reference with autolayout for positioning, ...

I'm using autolayout and you should avoid giving actual numbers, but it is also possible using bounds. Also be aware of if the user navigates away you have to cancel the task!